# Get Absolute location of Any Control in Objective C IPad App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, location

Im wondering if there is anyway that you can get the absolute location of a control in a ipad/iphone application. e.g. I have a TextField which is within a child of a child of a view. I want to know the X and Y values in relation to the top Parent View (e.g. currently the x and Y of the textfield return 10 and 10 because that is it's frame location within its own view, but I want to know this in relation to its parent which should be something like X = 10 and Y = 220). I need to make a generic method for this somehow. Hope this make sense.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You are looking for `-[UIView convertPoint:toView:]`.

For example, to get the origin of a view `view` in terms of its window's base coordinates, you would write:

```
CGPoint localPoint = [view bounds].origin;
CGPoint basePoint = [view convertPoint:localPoint toView:nil];
```

If you instead want to convert the point into the coordinate system of some other view within the same window, you can use that view as the `toView:` argument instead of `nil`:

```
NSAssert([view window] == [otherView window],
        @"%s: Views must be part of the same window.", __func__);
CGPoint otherPoint = [view convertPoint:localPoint toView:otherView];
```

Because different coordinate systems can have different scales, you might find `-convertRect:toView:` to be more useful, depending on what you're planning to do with the coordinates. There are also analogous `-fromView:` versions of both the point and rect conversion methods.

Comment: What if you don't know/have access to the view containing the point?